# Django Admin add edit/create buttons to Parent

Tags: python, django, django-admin, celery, django-celery

I'm trying to add an add and edit link to my Django admin for the ForeignKey field category. I already have this on the schedule field, however this is handled by djcelery and i cannot figure out how they do this:

[image]

My categories field currently looks like this:

[image]

Both fields are simply added to the admin screen through a foreign key relation.

Is there any default settings for this in Django admin?

Answer (score 0):

Facepalm! I got the desiredresult once i added a admin for categories:

```
admin.site.register(Category)
```

[image]

However, if any one know how to hide the Categories list from the main admin screen, please update my answer.

[image]

(Would also want to hide 'Categories' from this menu)